# stackoverflowexception solution in C#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

How can I prevent this exception to happen as I have to attain some values from one class and pass it to another class where as it's object is already in that class??

My first class is:

```
     public partial class Rack : UserControl
     {
        ContainerAdmin a = new ContainerAdmin();
        public Rack()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

       public string getposition()
       {
        PositionLabel.Text = Regex.Replace(PositionLabel.Text, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
        return PositionLabel.Text;
       }
    }
```

And my other class is :

```
     public partial class ContainerAdmin : UserControl, IDataConsumer<ContainerAdminAssemblyAdapter>
    {
       public ContainerAdminAssemblyAdapter Adapter { get; set; }

       Rack[] racking = new Rack[64];
    }
```

A recursive loop will occur so I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 4):

You have a situation where creating a ContainerAdmin creates an array of Racks which then creates a ContainerAdmin which then creates an array of Racks and so on. It's like a function calling itself without a stop condition and that's why you're getting the stack overflow.

To solve this problem, you have to restructure your program. In either the ContainerAdmin or Rack class, you shouldn't be creating new instances of the other. Using my psychic powers, I'd guess that the Rack objects should be provided with a preexisting ContainerAdmin object.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a circular loop here. In other words you have created circular dependency here. That is why you are getting this exception.

> Rack is creating instance of ContainerAdmin and ContainerAdmin is
>   creating instance of Rack.